How can I search for a text present in a code snippet in a DM or channel in Slack?
How can I search for a text present in a code snippet in a DM or channel in Slack? I want to only run the search across code snippets, and not other texts.

Search by File then filter for Snippets
See Shrinking the haystack: how to narrow search results in Slack


Thanks! Follow-up: How can I search for a text present in a code block in a DM or channel in Slack?
